# Angular JS + get an attribute from a list of objects into Array using $filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, filter

I need get specific attributes from items within a array of objects.

**Example**

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {"name":"as","code":"9874"},
  {"name":"sd","code":"9541"},
  {"name":"df","code":"1574"},
  {"name":"fg","code":"5874"},
  {"name":"gh","code":"3652"},
  {"name":"hj","code":"1452"}
]
```

**Result**

```
var newArrayOfObjectsFiltered = [
  {"code":"9874"},
  {"code":"9541"},
  {"code":"1574"},
  {"code":"5874"},
  {"code":"3652"},
  {"code":"1452"}
]
```

As you can see, I want the code property from each object in the list.

I already tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var filteredArray = filterFilter(arrayOfObjects, 'code');
```

Comment: so you just want to remove the "name" property from all the items in the list? you don't have to use filter for that

Answer (score 1):

You need custom filter like this

```
app.filter('myFilter, 'function(){
  return function(array){
    if(!arrayOfObjects) return [];
    return arrayOfObjects.map(function(obj){
      return { "code": obj.code }
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not even use a filter for that unless you need it in one of your templates. If you only filter things in your controller or service you can simply use `Array.prototype.map()` and reminds of a more functional way. In combination with utility libraries like `lodash` you can do it as follows:

```
arrayOfObjects.map(function(item) {
    return _.pick(item, 'code');
});
```

Pick only takes the specified properties.

**_.pick(object, [predicate], [thisArg])**

> Creates an object composed of the picked object properties. Property
>   names may be specified as individual arguments or as arrays of
>   property names. If predicate is provided it’s invoked for each
>   property of object picking the properties predicate returns truthy
>   for. The predicate is bound to thisArg and invoked with three
>   arguments: (value, key, object).

**Update 1**

In case you need it in a template, e.g. to filter a collection passed to `ng-repeat` you can simply insert the code snippet into a custom filter like so:

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('myCustomFilter', function() {
    return function(input, properties) {
        return input.map(function(item) {
            return _.pick(item, properties);
        });
    };
});
```

You can then use it like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in arrayOfObjects | myCustomFilter:['code']"></li>
```

The result will be that each item only has the specified properties.